# why is throwing a SoapException through WCF service seen as a FaultException?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am confused as when I throw a `SoapException` on the service side like so:

```
 Throw New SoapException("Error Message", SoapException.ClientFaultCode)
```

In the client side, the exception is seen as a `FaultException` - it goes into this catch

```
Catch ex As FaultException(Of ExceptionDetail)
```

Why isnt this a `SoapException` and therefore go into the below?

e.g.

```
Catch ex As SoapException
```

Comment: Fault exception is the exception contract in WCF any exceptions that occurs on the service will be reported as faultcontract to the client

Comment: Thanks, is this standard using soap 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you throw anything other than a
[`FaulException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.aspx)
or `FaultException(Of TDetail)` (which `SoapException` is not), WCF throws a `FaultException` instead.

I suspect you have `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` turned on? That's why WCF sends a `FaultException(Of ExceptionDetail)`, with the [`ExceptionDetail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.exceptiondetail.aspx) initialized from the exception you threw.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - so is throwing a `FaultException` the same as throwing a SOAP fault (soap standard 1.1) to the client?

Comment: As I understand it, when the server throws an exception (of any kind), WCF sends a SOAP message that contains a fault. This fault is then thrown on the client side as a `FaultException` (meaning a SOAP fault was received instead of a valid reply), so on the client side you will always get either a `FaultException` or a `FaultException(Of TDetail)`.

Comment: Thank you. That is my understanding as well